# Adding nodes to sddraft using minidom

Tags: arcgis-server, xml

I want to add this extension to an sddraft using minidom and can't figure out how to do it.
Some help would be great. 
To start with I'd like to find out how to add the first node SVCExtension xsi:type="typens:SVCExtension" right after Extensions xsi:type="typens:ArrayOfSVCExtension".

```
<SVCExtension xsi:type="typens:SVCExtension">
  <Enabled>true</Enabled>
  <Info xsi:type="typens:PropertySet">
    <PropertyArray xsi:type="typens:ArrayOfPropertySetProperty">
      <PropertySetProperty xsi:type="typens:PropertySetProperty">
        <Key>supportsSOAP</Key>
        <Value xsi:type="xs:string">false</Value>
      </PropertySetProperty>
      <PropertySetProperty xsi:type="typens:PropertySetProperty">
        <Key>supportsREST</Key>
        <Value xsi:type="xs:string">true</Value>
      </PropertySetProperty>
    </PropertyArray>
  </Info>
  <Props xsi:type="typens:PropertySet">
    <PropertyArray xsi:type="typens:ArrayOfPropertySetProperty"/>
  </Props>
  <TypeName>StreetDirectory</TypeName>
</SVCExtension>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that I'm not that stressed out I'm retaking this and managed to understand how minidom works.

In case it's useful to anyone, this is how you would modify an xml (with the complexity of an sddraft file) with minidom to accomplish what I first wanted to do.

**Be aware though** that an sddraft file with extra elements not present in it by default will fail when attempting to publish to ArcGIS Server (once staged).
Bad news for me, but at least I learned something new.

```
import xml.dom.minidom as dom

def addExtension (sddraft):

  sddraftDoc = dom.parse(sddraft)
  extensions = sddraftDoc.getElementsByTagName('Extensions').item(0)

  enable = sddraftDoc.createElement("Enabled")
  enable.appendChild(sddraftDoc.createTextNode("true"))

  keyName = sddraftDoc.createElement("Key")
  keyName.appendChild(sddraftDoc.createTextNode("supportsSOAP"))
  keyValue = sddraftDoc.createElement("Value")
  keyValue.setAttribute("xsi:type","xs:string")
  keyValue.appendChild(sddraftDoc.createTextNode("false"))
  setProp = sddraftDoc.createElement("PropertySetProperty")
  setProp.setAttribute("xsi:type","typens:PropertySetProperty")
  setProp.appendChild(keyName)
  setProp.appendChild(keyValue)

  keyName2 = sddraftDoc.createElement("Key")
  keyName2.appendChild(sddraftDoc.createTextNode("supportsREST"))
  keyValue2 = sddraftDoc.createElement("Value")
  keyValue2.setAttribute("xsi:type","xs:string")
  keyValue2.appendChild(sddraftDoc.createTextNode("true"))
  setProp2 = sddraftDoc.createElement("PropertySetProperty")
  setProp2.setAttribute("xsi:type","typens:PropertySetProperty")
  setProp2.appendChild(keyName2)
  setProp2.appendChild(keyValue2)

  propArray = sddraftDoc.createElement("PropertyArray")
  propArray.setAttribute("xsi:type","typens:ArrayOfPropertySetProperty")
  propArray.appendChild(setProp)
  propArray.appendChild(setProp2)

  info = sddraftDoc.createElement("Info")
  info.setAttribute("xsi:type","typens:PropertySet")
  info.appendChild(propArray)

  propArray2 = sddraftDoc.createElement("PropertyArray")
  propArray2.setAttribute("xsi:type","typens:ArrayOfPropertySetProperty")

  props = sddraftDoc.createElement("Props")
  props.setAttribute("xsi:type","typens:PropertySet")
  props.appendChild(propArray2)

  typname = sddraftDoc.createElement("TypeName")
  typname.appendChild(sddraftDoc.createTextNode("StreetDirectory"))

  soe = sddraftDoc.createElement("SVCExtension")
  soe.setAttribute("xsi:type","typens:SVCExtension")
  soe.appendChild(enable)  
  soe.appendChild(info)
  soe.appendChild(props)
  soe.appendChild(typname)
  extensions.appendChild(soe)

  if os.path.exists(sddraft): os.remove(sddraft)
  f = open(sddraft,"w")
  sddraftDoc.writexml(f)
  f.close()
```